# Bootstrap 4.6 relative nav-link tab targets for replicating structures (e.g., multiple interactive rows, tab groups) & selectpicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a SQL where clause interface with bootstrap 4.6 where the container has 1+ rows consisting of columns: left and right operands separated by an operator dropdown.  The operands are nav-tabs and let the user select between a table/attribute dropdowns, and a literal value.  I have a question about how data-target is resolved when the user selects a tab. I would like to do this using data-target attributes that reference classes rather than ids so that I can create replicates without having to generate unique ids. I have a secondary (minor) issue with selectpicker initialization.

Components of the comparison are nested inside column divs along these lines:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row comparison">
      <div class="whereLHS col-md"> ... </div>
      <div class="col-"> operator spec </div>
      <div class="whereRHS col-md"> ... </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

When the data-targets reference ids, as in the slightly simplified fragment from the left-hand side specification below, everything works.  See this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marie_r/1mrbkLaz/) for a functioning specification with all three columns.

```
<div class="WhereLHS col-md">
    <nav>
        <div class="nav-tabs nav" role="tablist">
            <button class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" 
                data-target="#lhswhereTblAttr" type="button" role="tab">
                Field
            </button>
            <button class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" data-target="#lhswhereVal" 
                type="button" role="tab">
                Value
            </button>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- Operand to a where clause -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <!-- Table/Attribute specifiers -->
        <div class="tab-pane active whereTblAttr" role="tabpanel" 
            id="lhswhereTblAttr" aria-label="select table attribute">
            <select class="selectpicker table" data-title="table" data-live-search="true">
                <option>some table</option>
                <option>yea another table</option>
            </select>
            <select class="selectpicker attr" data-title="field" id="lhswhereVal" 
                data-live-search="true">
                <!-- updated by JS to contain current table attriubtes -->
                <option>selected attr 1</option>  
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- Value operand -->
        <div class="tab-pane whereVal" role="tabpanel">
            <input class="form-control valueToCompare" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I **change the data-targets to specify classes rather than ids** (see this revised [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/marie_r/twy5vk3j/)), I find that whichever tab I mark as active functions properly, but the inactive tab becomes associated with the left-hand side fields, suggesting that the class search may be global, or at least at a higher level than the div which contains the <nav> and the the <div class="tab-content"/>.  I removed the id attributes and changed the data-targets in the nav-link tab buttons to reference these via class selectors, e.g. "selectpicker.table".  When I run a jquery to find classes rooted at the operand div, I can identify the targets appropriately.  I had hoped that in the running page the target search would start with siblings of the nav element, but this does not appear to be the case.  I think that it is finding elements on both the left and right-hand sides and using the first one.  As can be seen in the [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marie_r/twy5vk3j/), the dropdowns are no longer separate and the right tab-pane continues to show the text input box when the field (table/attr) tab is clicked.  Is there a way to specify the target appropriately?  I'd like to keep the left and right hand sides separate as well as create mulitple instances of these without having to generate unique ids each time (which of course can be done if that's what it takes).

*minor issue*:  I also noticed that selectpicker was not initializing correctly. When the page loaded, the table and attribute selectors did not display even when their tab was set to active.  Switching to the other tab and switching back would cause the select elements to display.  I found that removing fade from the tab-pane div (no longer in the fiddles) resolved the problem, but I would be interested in understanding if this is a bug or an incorrect specifciation on my part.

Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Solution to minor issue:  When selectpicker is changed programmatically, one needs to invoke selectpicker("refresh") on the selectpicker object.